# How to make cppcheck stop on error

Tags: c++, c, cppcheck

I use cppcheck to look for errors.
now I'm looking for a way the stop the cppcheck run after he found the first error.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That would be handy if checking consumes a lot of time. It is common practice to provide such an option. For example gcc offers `-Wfatal-errors`. Anyway, there is no reason for -3 rating for this question.

Comment: @VTT other than lack of research.

Comment: i saw this manual you put here...
didn't found any help there. so i asked here...
didn't know its not allowed :/

Comment: Here is not a platform for ask for code. Please show some effort

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf
There seems to be no option to stop at first issue.  You could always contact them directly though to confirm or request the feature.